# Disable/enable scroll view in a different class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a class ViewController which inhertis from UIViewController:

```
@interface PagerViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

and here I can turn on and off the scroll option like this:

```
[self setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

I addrf some other ViewController class as a child but the problem is that when I try to enable or disable the scroll there, it doesn't recognize the "setScrollEnabled". In this class I got a button and I want to disable "setScrollEnabled" when the button is pushed. How can I do this?

Comment: Use NSNotification, which will allow you to call method of PagerViewController class, where you can set scrollEnabled property. Search examples about NSNotification / local notification. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I am glad that your problem resolved. I have added the same in answer, can you please accept and upvote the same. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSNotification`, which will allow you to call method of `PagerViewController` class, where you can set `scrollEnabled` property.

Search examples about `NSNotification` / `Local Notification.`

It will solve your problem.